# Dat.gui and Three.js - add / remove from scene with a single checkbox

Tags: javascript, three.js, dat.gui

I have multiple models in a scene which I currently control by placing them inside a function and calling the function when I want to load them.

I'd like to have dat.gui add or remove the object based on a checkbox.

I've successfully loaded the object using dat.gui, but I can't figure out how to remove it (using the same checkbox).

I know I can remove the object using a scene.delete(object) or similar but I don't know how to tie this all into a single checkbox.

Comment: You can do all the stuff you want with the active object in the scene, using `.onChange()` event of a dat.gui controller.

Comment: I've tried it using this: `var params ={checkbox=false}; gui.add(params, checkbox').onChange(function (value) { model(); }); `This adds the model when I press the checkbox but won't do anything when I "disable" the checkbox. And then if I press it again, it loads the model again (it's .5 opacity so I can see it being added to the scene again each time I tick the checkbox. Is there a way to unload it with the same tickbox?

Comment: You pass the `value` in the callback function of the event, but you don't check what value it has. Check it and add a condition, like `if (value == something){model();} else {removeModel();}`.